Is my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API endpoint respecting OAuth 2.0 standards?
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API to serve as an Auth API using OAuth 2.0 for our company's software.
Here's the flow: when a user selects "Connect with [Company Name] account" in a company app, they are redirected to a separate login page.
This page keeps the required OAuth 2.0 info from the redirection (redirect URI, client ID, etc.).
The user enters their credentials, which are sent to an Auth API endpoint for validation. This endpoint logs session information and returns an operation result with a success boolean, an error message string (if any), and a session token upon success.
After what all the information are meant to be sent to the authorize endpoint.
This API will be used to authenticate Next.js web apps, native .NET apps and Android applications.
My question: is this endpoint respecting the OAuth 2.0 standards? If not, what should I do differently?
Also any recommendations or help would be greatly appreciated. I'm aware I need to implement PKCE with a code challenge.
Here's my current implementation:
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("authorize")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Authorize(string responseType, string clientId, string redirectUri, string scope, string state, string sessionToken)
{
    // Validate the client
    var client = await _oAuthClientService.GetClientByIdAsync(int.Parse(clientId));

    if (client == null || client.RedirectUri != redirectUri)
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid client or redirect URI");
    }

    // Get the user ID from the session token (created when authenticating with credentials)
    var userSession = await _userSessionService.GetUserSessionFromToken(sessionToken);
    
    var authorizationCode = new OauthAuthorizationCode
    {
        AuthorizationCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        ClientId = client.ClientId,
        UserId = userSession.User.UserId,
        ExpiresAt = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15),
        RedirectUri = redirectUri,
        Scope = scope
    };

    await _oAuthAuthorizationCodeService.AddAuthorizationCodeAsync(authorizationCode);

    return Redirect($"{redirectUri}?code={authorizationCode.AuthorizationCode}&state={state}");
}


Your current implementation appears to be on the right track for an OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint. You could also consider enabling the Authorization Code Expiry. You should ensure that the authorization code expires and cannot be reused.
